# Indexing XML recursively with xmldocument

Tags: c#, xml, recursion

i'm trying to add an "index" attribute to all XML nodes using recursion in C#.
My problem is that when i try to add an attribute to a node that does not have child nodes, it fails with a null reference.
for example, for a simple XML file (html) i want it to be like that:

```
<div index="1">
    <div index="1.1">
        <h2 index="1.1.1">some text1</h2>
        <h2 index="1.1.2">some text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div index="2">
    <table index="2.1">
        <tr index="2.1.1">
            <td index="2.1.1.1">some cell</td>
            <td index="2.1.1.2">some cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr index="2.1.2">
            <td index="2.1.2.1">some cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div index="3">
    <h1 index="3.1">some text</h1>
</div>
```

My function now looks like this:

```
  public static string TraverseNodes(XmlNode node,XmlDocument xmlDoc,bool isChild)
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (XmlNode subNode in node)
            {

                var child = subNode.ChildNodes[i];
                if (subNode.ChildNodes[i] != null)
                {
                    XmlAttribute typeAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("realIndex");
                    typeAttr.Value = (isChild ? (i+ ".") : "") + (i + 1);
                    subNode.Attributes.Append(typeAttr);
                }


                i++;
                TraverseNodes(subNode, xmlDoc, isChild);
            }
            return PrintXml(xmlDoc);

        }
```

maybe my whole approach is wrong. i'd be glad for any help.

Comment: Can you use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument? It's certainly possible to write this code with XmlDocument, but LINQ to XML is much cleaner... (Your sample would be easier to read with indentation, btw...)

Comment: It sure can be LINQ.
Any good idea how to achieve it?\

Comment: You've already got code - so what happens when you try that? (And why are you returning a string from this?)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use LINQ to XML for this. My first *somewhat inefficient* way of doing this would be:

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    int indexInLevel = element.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() + 1;
    var parent = element.Parent;
    string prefix = parent == null ? "" : (string) parent.Attribute("index") + ".";
    element.SetAttributeValue("index", prefix + indexInLevel);
}
```

Note that that will make your root element have an index of "1". It relies on the fact that `Descendants` traverses in document order, so the parent of any element will already have had an index attribute set before it traverses down to the children.

Now I said that's fairly inefficient, because it needs to count all the earlier siblings each time. You could make it more efficient with recursion instead, and be a bit more flexible too:

```
public void AssignIndexes(XElement element, string prefix, int index)
{
    string value = prefix + index;
    element.SetAttributeValue("index", value);
    value += "."; // As the prefix for all children
    int subindex = 1;
    foreach (var child in element.Elements())
    {
        AssignIndexes(child, value, subindex++);
    }
}

public void AssignIndexesToChildren(XElement element)
{
    int subindex = 1;
    foreach (var child in element.Elements())
    {
        AssignIndexes(child, "", subindex++);
    }
}
```

Now you can call `AssignIndexesToChildren(doc.Root)` and it will ignore the root element, but create "1" for the first child, etc.

Comment: that was perfect. thank you.
I only changed the subindex to ZERO and added inside the foreach by one. subindex++.
Any idea how to make it ignore the first element and not index it?

Comment: @Basilf: Sorry, I meant to use `subindex++` in the method call first. Do you mean "ignore the first element within each element"? Why would you do that?

Comment: jon i mean the root element. for example ignoring the <html> tag in a case of a html code

Comment: @Basilf: Will add something to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with XML linq, but code can be converted to straight xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<html>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<div>" +
                "<div>" +
                "<h2>some text1</h2>" +
                "<h2>some text</h2>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div>" +
                "<table>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>some cell</td>" +
                "<td>some cell</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>some cell</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</table>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div>" +
                "<h1>some text</h1>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            XElement body = doc.Descendants("body").FirstOrDefault();
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
            AddIndex(body, indexes);

        }
        static void AddIndex(XElement elements, List<int> indexes)
        {
            indexes.Add(0);
            foreach (XElement element in elements.Elements())
            {

                indexes[indexes.Count - 1] += 1;
                element.Add(new XAttribute("index", string.Join(".",indexes.Select(x => x.ToString()))));
                if (element.HasElements)
                {
                    AddIndex(element, indexes);
                }

            }
            indexes.RemoveAt(indexes.Count - 1);
        }
    }
}
​​
```

Answer (score 0):

1Ok, this is an option.  You'd call it with

```
AssignIndex(myXmlDoc.DocumentElement,0,0)
```

and it should work (not tested);

```
public static string AssignIndex(XmlNode node, int nodeIdx, int childIdx)
    {
        if (childIdx != 0) {
            XmlAttribute typeAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("realIndex");
            typeAttr.Value = (nodeIdx == 0 ? "": (nodeIdx+ ".")) + childIdx;
            node.Attributes.Append(typeAttr);
        }
        int i=1;
        foreach (XmlNode subNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            AssignIndex(subNode, childIdx, i++);
        }
    }
```